# Perl: Piping child stdout to parent process

Tags: perl, http, unix, stdout

In Perl, I can open a child process and pipe its output to the calling Perl script, like this:

```
open(my $cmd, '-|', 'ls') or die $!;
while (<$cmd>) {
   print $_;
}
```

This prints the files in my working folder, e.g.:

```
> foo.txt
> bar.txt
> ...
```

But I would like to do the same thing for a child process that remains open, e.g. to pipe `tcpdump`'s stdout to Perl, I attempt something similar:

```
open(my $cmd, '-|', 'tcpdump') or die $!;
while (<$cmd>) {
   print $_;
}
```

... but other than the `tcpdump` startup text, this doesn't mete out any http logs. It just seems to hang. What gives?

Comment: Suffering from buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was buffering issues. I needed to add the `-U` flag to `tcpdump`. This causes packets to be written as soon as they're received.